# github pull request from a single branch

Tags: github, pull-request

I have forked a master from upstream, and have created two branches from it. Is it possible to send in PR from a single branch?

I did that, and despite the github web UI is creating the PR against a single branch, I noticed the changes from the other branch is included in the PR request as well.

What's the correct way to send in PR from a single branch?

Comment: Can you provide more details, it's a little unclear what the problem you are having is.

Comment: I need to create github pull request from a single branch, when I do,  github creates pull request from both branches. I know it sounds impossible, but it is in fact happening. If you don't believe it, or still don't understand, I'm afraid that's the everything I can do, and you need to try to do the same thing to understand it (or see if you can creat PR from [here](https://github.com/suntong/wechaty/tree/emoji)). sorry, can't be more helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The likely problem is you didn't `git checkout master` before creating the second branch, then the second branch you created is descendant from the first branch you created. Just checkout to master before adding the second branch.